# Unable to click a text view using its text in calabash

Tags: android, ruby, calabash

I am new in calabash..I am unable to click a text view using its text.. My feature file looks like this

```html
 Feature: Login feature

Scenario: As a valid user I can log into my app
Given I enter text "hello" into field with id "search_autoCompleteTextView"
Then I press the enter button
Then I press the text view "click here"
```

My steps.rb file look like this

```html
require 'calabash-android/calabash_steps'
Given /^I enter text "([^\"]*)" into field with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text, id|
  enter_text("* id:'#{id}'", text)
end

Then /^I press the enter button$/ do
  perform_action('send_key_enter')
end

Then /^I press the text view "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text|
  tap_when_element_exists("* text:'#{text}'")
end
```

when I run the script using cmd - calabash-android run "path to apk" "path to feature file", its showing that 1 step is undefined

screenshot of command prompt

[image: command prompt]

But when I use calabash console 
touch("* text:'click here'"). It is working fine.

Comment: Is your step definition file in your features folder?  If I recall correctly, cucumber looks through features folder for step definitions.  If you do want to use a different location, you can include the steps file from a different location with a command line option.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your screen shot of output. There is a slight difference in your syntax and the syntax which is shown in the command prompt output.

The correct syntax is :

```
Then /^I press the text view "([^"]*)"$/ do  |text|
```

There is additional character " \ " in your step definition which you need to remove.

Hope this helps :) Marks this answer as accepted if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have space syntax error,

your code:

```
Then /^I press the text view "([^\"]*)"$/ do  |text|
    tap_when_element_exists("* text:'#{text}'")
end
```

modified :

```
Then /^I press the text view "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text|
    tap_when_element_exists("* text:'#{text}'")
end
```

extra space between "do" & "|text|" try modified and let me know.

Comment: then do one thing, just copy that step which is shown in console error and replace it with your old step. this should work 100% if still failing then some other issue we need look this issue some other way.

Comment: Then /^I press view with text "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text| touch("*text:'#{text}'") end         
to
Then(/^I press view with text "([^\"]*)"$/) do |text| touch("*text:'#{text}'") end

Comment: if possible can you send me the project structure screenshot

Comment: yeah sure, email me : tech.tock.tech@gmail.com